# Assigning command line arguments to functions

Tags: c++, function, void, argv, argc

Lets say I wanted to open a function (it opens a file, does something with it, then spits out the results to a different file). Using argv and argc, and from going through all the tutorials online, I'm assuming that if i print argv[0] i get the file name. 
My question is how do i set lets say the next argv[1.2.n] to a function. So if the user were to type in open (after the user is in the program directory), it would open that function. 
Something like:

```
  void file();
```

...

```
  if (argv[1] == open){
            file();
         }
```

Comment: your description is quite unclear. what different parameters should your program accept, and what should they do? also note that argv[0] will contain the name of the program

Comment: I believe you are describing what is called parameter unpacking in Python. Is that correct?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: There is a [close-reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/) for questions that are unclear. Please use it.

Comment: The common term is not to "open" a function, but to "call it". Can you improve your question, please? It is not fully clear what you want to do.

Comment: @BjörnPollex I do. I just try to ask for more details first if I see chances of the question being salvagable, or if I suspect that it's maybe only me not getting the question ;)

Comment: @nyarlathotep: For that reason closed questions are now displayed as **[on-hold]** for the first five days. This is done to emphasize that, if the OP improves the question, it will be reconsidered.

Comment: @BjörnPollex ah good to know, I'll be quicker with the close vote then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv` is of type `char*[]` (array of char* pointers). You cannot directly compare string constants (type `char*`), which you need to quote. Instead, I suggest you to convert it to a c++ string type:

```
#include <string>

void file(){   
     // ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(argc>=2)
        {
                if(std::string(argv[1]) == "open")
                {
                        file();
                }

        }
        else
        {
                // print usage
        }
}
```

Comment: `argv` is of type `char**`.  There is no such thing as a type `*char[]` in C++, and `char*[]` cannot occur as the type of a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The first string in argv isn't the first command line argument, it's usually the path to the exe. I recommend putting the command line arguments in an easy data structure.

```
vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);
```

Now you can pass the vector to your functions.

Comment: According to the standard, `argv[0]` should be "the name used to invoke the program", not the path to the `.exe`.  Of course, in practice, this isn't implementable in Unix, and you can get just about anything in `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters to your function:

```
void file(int * argc, char * * argv)
{
    //
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
  if (argv[1] == open)
  {
     file(argc, argv);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking.  If the goal is to
call different functions depending on one of the arguments, the
usual solution is to use a map of strings to pointers to
functions, and then do something like:

```
MapType::const_iterator entry = map.find( argv[1] );
if ( entry == map.end() ) {
    std::cerr << "Unknown function " << argv[1] << std::endl;
    returnCode = 1;
} else {
    (*entry->second)();
}
```